# If $I$ is a prime ideal in a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and $S_1AS_2 \subseteq I$, then either $S_1 \subseteq I$ or $S_2 \subseteq I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Murphy's "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory":

[image]

Can someone explain why we have $S_j \subseteq A S_j A$?

I can prove this if $S_j$ is a sub $C^*$-algebra of $A$ or if $A$ is unital.

Attempt:

Let $(u_\lambda)$ be an approximate unit for $A$. If $x\in S_j$, then somehow we should be able to write $x$ as a norm-limit of some net in $AS_jA$. Maybe we can prove something like
$$x=\lim_\lambda u_\lambda^{1/2} x u_\lambda^{1/2}$$

But I don't see why that should hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\|u_\lambda\|\leq1$, as long as we approximate on the left and write simultaneously, we obtain $x=\lim_\lambda u_\lambda xu_\lambda$ for all $x$.  Indeed, fix $x\in A$ and $\varepsilon>0$.  There exists $\lambda_0$ such that $\|xu_\lambda-x\|<\varepsilon$ and $\|u_\lambda x-x\|<\varepsilon$ for $\lambda\geq \lambda_0$.  For such $\lambda$, we have
$$\|u_\lambda xu_\lambda-x\|\leq\|u_\lambda\|\|xu_\lambda-x\|+\|u_\lambda x-x\|<2\varepsilon.$$